# How to change listen_addresses to * from localhost in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, redhat

I want to change the `listen_addresses` of my postgres database to `*`

I am using the command

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses TO '*';
```

But the value of the parameter is not changing to `*`.

Am I doing anything wrong with the command?

Currently my configuration in `postgresql.conf` is overwritten by `postgresql.auto.conf`.

Comment: Changing the listen address requires to restart Postgres. Did you do that? Also: `alter system` never writes to `postgresql.conf` so the fact that the change appears in `postgresql.auto.conf` is correct

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your answer after restarting it seems to change the listening address.